# Excel VBA Type Mismatch referencing Cell.Value

Tags: vba, excel

Hi sorry this is almost certainly going to be a "doh" moment but I haven't coded for a long time and I'm a bit rusty.

I have a cell value which I keep getting a type mismatch when I try and treat it as a string, yet CStr and testing for IsNull etc don't seem to help. Grateful for some advice.

```
Set ClientTable = SourceBook.Sheets("Source Data").Range("extdata")
For Each rng1 In ClientTable.Columns(1).Cells
    'if not first row (header row) and the customer name is matching the selected customer
    If (i <> 0) And (rng1.Value = SourceBook.Sheets("Source Data").Range("C1")) Then
        If Not IsNull(ClientTable.Columns(6).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value) Then
            MsgBox ClientTable.Columns(6).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value ' type mismatch here
        End If
        With Sheets("Contacts").Range("A1")
            .Offset(rowToWriteTo, 0).Value = ClientTable.Columns(6).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value ' first name
            .Offset(rowToWriteTo, 1).Value = ClientTable.Columns(2).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value ' last name
            .Offset(rowToWriteTo, 5).Value = ClientTable.Columns(3).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value ' email
            .Offset(rowToWriteTo, 6).Value = ClientTable.Columns(4).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value ' DDI
            .Offset(rowToWriteTo, 7).Value = ClientTable.Columns(7).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value ' mobile
            .Offset(rowToWriteTo, 8).Value = ClientTable.Columns(5).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value ' title
        End With
        rowToWriteTo = rowToWriteTo + 1

    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
```

If I remove this bit of code the Sheets("Contacts").Range("A1") assignments all work fine.

PS: use of MsgBox is just for debugging.  Trying to assign ClientTable.Columns(6).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value to a string variable produces the same error.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression `ClientTable.Columns(6).Cells.Offset(i, 0).Value` results in an array of values because `Columns(6)` is a `Range` object with multiple cells. You can't assign this array to a string. Maybe you should use `ClientTable.Cells(i, 6).Value` instead. So you get a single value.